# Entering large file of sql to phpmyadmin database

Tags: php

What is the SQL code to import an database to phpMyAdmin? I have tried using the import tab but it does not allow to import as the file size is too large than the given limit???

Comment: you'd be best off importing the file through the command line mysql client

Comment: If you are on a hosted environment and do not have access to command line, the only solution I see is to break up the file in smaller ones.

Comment: Did you tried to upload after zipping ? for instance the file name should look like :: your_db.sql.zip

Comment: Ya I changed the file to archive format and changed the name in the format of sql.zip then it was uploaded correclty. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MySql CLI:

```
> mysql -uUser -pPassword

> use DatabaseName

> source full_path_till_file.sql
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use BigDump from http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/. Just put this script and your big SQL file on FTP and run the script. I tried it on ~2GB SQL file and it works without any problems.

Comment: I downloaded it. It would be very important. Thanks so much